# Does kivy's Window.softinput_mode work on raspberry-pi?

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, keyboard, kivy

I'm creating a GUI on a raspberry-pi touchscreen and I have the keyboard_mode in kivy's config.ini set to dock.  The docked keyboard takes up almost half of the raspberry-pi screen and covers up some Text Input widgets that I have on my program.  I did some research and found that you can set Window.softinput_mode to either `pan`, `resize`, etc. to change the window size when the keyboard pops up.

I put the below code line before the main body of the code:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.softinput_mode = 'pan'
```

This didn't change anything in my program. 
Does the raspberry-pi support `softinput_mode`? and if so, how do I use it correctly?

If `softinput_mode` is not supported, is there a way to change the height of the docked keyboard?

Comment: Which Kivy version are you using? Have you tried `Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"`?

Comment: @ikolim I'm using kivy 1.10, the latest version on its website. I've tried "below_target" and nothing happened, like all of the other options.